# How to change the default IME input method in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

I would like to know if there is a way to change the default input method while writing in Japanese.

I have several keyboard languages installed and change between them using the shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. They all work well.

But the thing is, when I select Japanese, the default input method is Half-width alphanumeric when I want Hiragana to be the default. I can change the input method through the taskbar, but I have to do this every time I open a program. So I tried changing the preferences, to no effect:

1. I select the Japanese keyboard.
2. I right-click on the "A" or "あ" that appears on the taskbar to open IME options, and go to "Properties".
3. I open "Advances Settings for Microsoft IME".

[image]

What is wrong?  What should I change so that the default is Hiragana? If this fails, is there a keyboard shortcut to change between Hiragana, Half-width alphanumeric, etc, so that I don't have to use the mouse every time?

Comment: What about _Switching input methods_ section in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings`?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same trouble and have not found a complete solution, but I found a shortcut that might help. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> should let you switch from half-width alphanumeric to hiragana. As far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to work for the other input methods for Japanese, though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to make the Japanese IME your default IME by going to Control Panel -> Language and then removing the English option. You can then use the Japanese IME as the English input option by simply pressing Alt+~ to easily switch between hiragana and direct input (English). That at least reduces your keyboards by one. FYI, I use Google Japanese input. I find it much better than the native Microsoft Japanese IME.

Answer (score 0):

These are the keyboard shortcuts for the Japanese language for US keyboard.
The reference is from Quita.com (聞いた) a similar question and answer / blog site in Japanese. See [link](https://qiita.com/moutend/items/07a7bd19783234bd4159) for further detail.

```
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
|   日本語入力の状態                       |    ショートカット     |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 半角英数 <-> 全角ひらがな(全角カタカナ)    | Alt + `             |
| Half-width Alphanumeric <-> Full-width Hiragana (Katakana)    |
| 半角英数 <-> 全角ひらがな                 | Shift + CapsLock    |
| Half-width Alphanumeric <-> Full-width Hiragana               |
| 半角英数 -> 全角ひらがな                  | Alt + CapsLock      |
| Half-width Alphanumeric -> Full-width Hiragana                |
| 半角英数 -> 全角ひらがな                  | Ctrl + CapsLock     |
| Half-width Alphanumeric -> Full-width Hiragana                |
| 全角ひらがな -> 全角カタカナ              | Alt + CapsLock      |
| Half-width Alphanumeric -> Full-width Katakana                |
| 全角カタカナ -> 全角ひらがな              | Ctrl + CapsLock     |
| Half-width Alphanumeric -> Full-width Hiragana                |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Note:

```
<-> is a toggle
-> is unidirectional
```

Short answer is

> Alt + `

I cannot make

> Shift + Capslock

to work in my japanese keyboard though.